# Distribution properties of the arithmetic mean of a subordinated Gaussian Process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a stationary standard gaussian sequence and $G$ be a function such that $\operatorname{E}\left[G(X_1)\right]=0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(G(X_1))<\infty$. Further let the hermite rank of $G$ be 1 and $T_n:= s_n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n G(X_i)$ be the appropriately standardisized arithmetic mean of the stationary sequence $(G(X_i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$.
Is in this case $$P(T_n\leq x)=P\left(s_n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n G(X_i)\leq x\right)$$ differentiable? Thanks a lot!